# Pandas doesn't seem to "see" my index

Tags: pandas

I'm a long time user of Python, but am just starting Pandas.
I'm using the latest anaconda download of Pandas 0.18 and Python 3.5 in IPython 4.2.0 on a Mac running OS-X 10.11.6.
I have a data frame whose first few column names are: Date, Time, H2O16c_ppm, H2O_16cppm_se...  It happens that the dates in the Date column are all identical and I'd like to drop that column.  However, when I tell IPython:
"In [80]: redu1 = test_data.drop(['Date'])", it tells me: "ValueError: labels ['Date'] not contained in axis".  In the data file, the Date header is prefixed by several spaces, but including those spaces in my drop command doesn't make any difference.  I'm obviously doing something wrong, but what?  \\\
Turns out the leading spaces WAS the problem.  I had tried prefixing the column name with what I thought were the right number of spaces, but hadn't counted correctly somehow.

Comment: Grab the columns with `test_data.columns` and compare the values returned with what you're using. The error basically means that what you're using is not a column in the dataframe. It's likely that the first value from  `test_data.columns` is your `Date` column, so you can grab it easily from there. Also, with a snippet of your data you're guaranteed to get better answers here.

Answer (score 0):

The `drop` method works on the index by default. Use `axis=1` to drop a column

```
 redu1 = test_data.drop(['Date'], axis=1)
```